# Empty associations for fields_for if the content is added dynamically via jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, nested-form-for

I built a form_for with 4 associated models. I created nested fields_for which can be added dynamically with the code below. My form works if I call the 'edit' method but if I use the method below to add new data the fields_for remains empty and are not shown.

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

This works fine if I only wants to add one form of a model. But if the added content which have fields_for for nested fields_for the text_fields are not created. In my opinion it is because I do not build the associations. How can I fix this method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar method (based on [Itay Grudev's blog post](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes)), in which I set the `child_index` as `nil` and then use jQuery to replace it with a timestamp (so that many records can be added avoiding them having the same `id`).

So, in my `application_helper.rb` file I've got:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name = nil, f = nil, association = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block) 
    f, association, options, html_options = name, f, association, options if block_given? 
    options = {} if options.nil? 
    html_options = {} if html_options.nil? 

    if options.include? :locals 
      locals = options[:locals]
    else 
      locals = { } 
    end 
    if options.include? :partial 
      partial = options[:partial] 
    else 
      partial = association.to_s.singularize + '_fields'
    end 

    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new 
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: nil) do |builder| 
      render(partial, locals.merge!( fields: builder)) 
    end 

    html_options['data-form-prepend'] = raw CGI::escapeHTML( fields ) 
    html_options['href'] = '#'

    content_tag(:a, name, html_options, &block)
```

end

And then I added a Coffeescript file called `dynamic_tables.js.coffee` in which I find the newly added fields, replace their name with a timestamp (so they're all indexed as a group) and prepend the form to a  target (a hidden element I added at the bottom of my table and marked it as `prepend_target`). So I've got:

```
$('[data-form-prepend]').click (e) ->
    target = $($(this).attr('prepend_target'))
    obj = $($(this).attr('data-form-prepend'))
    current_time = (new Date).getTime()
    obj.find('input, select, textarea').each ->
      $(this).attr 'name', ->
        $(this).attr('name').replace 0, current_time
      return
    obj.insertBefore target
    false
```

That should do the trick. Hope this helps.